# Second-order PDE with seven variables

Tags: differential-equations

I need to solve the following partial differential equation in seven variables with four boundary conditions. I don't think Mathematica has the capacity to solve this differential equation.

[image]

Do you know of scientific packages which can be used to solve this equation and plot graphs of the dependent variable against each of the independent variables?

Comment: It looks like you missed to include the actual equation.

Comment: I've attached it now.

Comment: This equation seem to be off second order to me

Comment: This looks like it's only an equation in three variables ($t_x,r_x,\theta_x$) plus a time-like variable $u$. $t_y,r_y,\theta_y$ only seem to be parameters, but there are no derivatives with regards to these variables. Is this correct? If so, you basically have a 3+1 dimensional advection diffusion equation with some wacky weights.

Comment: That's true. $t_y$, $r_y$ and $\theta_y$ only appear in one of the boundary conditions. How would you solve a $3+1$-dimensional advection diffusion equation with wacky weights though?

Comment: I think that you're missing one boundary condition for $r_x$.